# Aspose Sharepoint and Alfresco

Tags: sharepoint, alfresco, aspose

Does [Aspose.Words for SharePoint](http://www.aspose.com/categories/sharepoint-components/aspose.words-for-sharepoint/default.aspx) work with Alfresco running on Linux or does it only work within a Windows SharePoint server?

Comment: Do you mean [Aspone.Network for Sharepoint](http://www.aspose.com/categories/sharepoint-components/aspose.network-for-sharepoint/default.aspx) or something else?

Comment: @Gagravarr Well the question for me is whether or not Aspose SharePoint will work with Alfresco or not, I saw it here http://www.aspose.com/categories/sharepoint-components/aspose.total-for-sharepoint/default.aspx

Comment: I believe there isn't one "Aspose SharePoint" product. You've linked there to "Aspose.Total for SharePoint", is that the Aspsose product you want to use? Or do you want Aspose.Network for SharePoint or something else?

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks, I've edited the question, Aspose.Words for SharePoint is what I'm interested in

Comment: Sorry to dig this question up but did you find a answer to you solution. If yes could you share it we us me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@eon

I work as developer evangelist at Aspose and I would like to share some details with you regarding your query.

Aspose.Words for Sharepoint works with Microsoft Sharepoint Server. It is used to convert or combine Word documents with in Sharepoint. As far as your question is concerned, I'm afraid, it is not very clear that how you want to use Aspose.Words with Alfresco. If you could shed some light on that then it would be easier to guide you.

However, as I can see Alfresco is based on Java. Does it provide an interface for Java development as well? Would it be feasible to use a Jar file to process Word documents programmatically with Alfresco? If so, you may try [Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/default.aspx). This component is a simple Jar file which allows you to [create, edit, and convert Word files using Java programming](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/index.html). Please see if this might help in your scenario.

Comment: thanks for that, I have been using Aspose.Words for Java and am very happy with it. Without knowing the exact use-cases that Aspose.Words is used for in SharePoint I wanted to know if it could be leverage in a Java based SharePoint implementation, i.e. Alfresco

Comment: Alfresco can "pretend" to be Sharepoint server. If you install the SPP module, it will listen for and answer sharepoint protocol requests. As far as something like word or excel is concerned, it is talking to Sharepoint, but it's really Alfresco. I guess the question is - does Aspose.Words talk to SharePoint using the public sharepoint protocols, or does it embed itself deeply using private APIs?

Comment: @Gagravarr and eon, Aspose.Words for Sharepoint (AWSP) uses public SharePoint Object Model API like SPList and SPFile classes etc. Although, it doesn't embed deeply using private APIs, but still it is based on .NET Framework and that's why it's probably not supported on Alfresco. So, in such scenario Aspose.Words for Java might be helpful. It requires a little extra Java programming, but it will provide a lot of features of Aspose.Words for Java in addition to converting/combining documents.